# не умещаются все 256 символов в консоль visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Использую visual studio 2022 не могу найти параметр для удлинения чтения в консоли символов, начинается отчёт от 28 символа, из 256. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить 22 года визуал студио использую.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    
    for (int i = 0; i <= 255; i++)
    {
        cout << "code = " << i << "\t" << "char = " << (char)i << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: *начинается отчёт от 28 символа, из 256* - покажите код, который выводит эти строки

Comment: @user7860670 я не автор вопроса, но оказалось, что проблема воспроизводится даже вот таким python-однострочником `for i in range(256): _=sys.stdout.buffer.write(f'code = {i}\tchar = '.encode('utf-8') + bytes([i]) + b'\n')`

Comment: @andreymal Ну в том, что непечатаемые символы не попадут на экран и еще потенциально его исказят нет ничего удивительно. Это проблема кода вывода, а не консоли.

Comment: @user7860670 и причина на самом деле очень проста — 27 это escape-символ, а после него в слове `code` первая буква `c` — и в сумме получается [команда сброса консоли](https://vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html#RIS) (правда, я что-то пропустил, с каких это пор стандартная консоль винды стала поддерживать такие escape-команды)

Comment: @user7860670 ах да, для воспроизведения проблемы ещё оказалось нужно выполнить `os.system('cls')` перед выводом escape-символа. Видимо, команда cls переключает консоль в какой-то другой режим?

Comment: Код нужно добавить текстом, а не скриншотом

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за ответ, вы мне помогли!